# Initial parameters in nonlinear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression

I want to learn how to do nonlinear regression in R. I managed to learn the basics of the `nls` function, but how we know it's crucial in nonlinear regression to use good initial parameters. I tried to figure out how `selfStart` and `getInitial` functions works but failed. The documentation is very scarce and not very usefull. I wanted to learn these functions via a simple simulation data. I simulated data from logistic model:

```
n<-100 #Number of observations
d<-10000 #our parameters
b<--2 
e<-50 


set.seed(n)
X<-rnorm(n, -e/b, 2) #Thanks to it we'll have many observations near the point where logistic function grows the faster
Y<-d/(1+exp(b*X+e))+rnorm(n, 0, 200) #I simulate data
```

Now I wanted to do regression with a function f(x)=d/(1+exp(b*x+e)) but I don't know how to use `selfStart` or `getInitial`. Could you help me? But please, don't tell me about `SSlogis`. I'm aware it's a functon destined to find initial parameters in logistic regression, but It seems it only works in regression with one explanatory variable and I'd like to learn how to do logistic regression with more than one explanatory variables and even how to do general nonlinear regression with a function that I defined mysefl.

I will be very gratefull for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the calculus of good initial parameters fails in R. The aim of my answer is to provide a method to find good enough initial parameters.

Note that a non-iterative method exists which doesn't requires initial parameters. The principle is explained in this paper, pp.37-46 : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

A simplified version is shown below.

If the results are not sufficient, they can be used as initial parameters in an usual non-linear regression software such as in R.

[image]

A numerical example is shown below. Usually the number of points is much higher. Here it is deliberately low in order to make easier the checking when one edit the code and check it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: Thanks for your response
1. I didn't write that R faild to find good initial parameters. I wrote that I just don't know how to use selfStart or getInitial functions to find them :) 
2. I don't understand the description of your algorithm (for example what A, B and C are), but it seems it's destined only for logistic regression? I pasted my simulated data from logistic model just as an example. But I'd like to learn how can I find good initial parameters in every nonlinear regression in R. 
3. Unfortunately the paper you posted is in French and I don't know this language :(

Comment: @JJacquelin, In R these calculations would be `x <- seq(22.5, 27, .5);
y <- c(67, 180, 474, 1192, 2689, 5000, 7311, 8808, 9526, 9820);
S <- cumsum(c(0, (1/y[-1] + 1/y[-length(y)]) / 2 * diff(x)));
fm1 <- lm(S ~ x + I(1/y));
a <- 1/coef(fm1)[["x"]];
fm2 <- lm(log(a/y - 1) ~ x);
b <- coef(fm2)[[2]];
c <- coef(fm2)[[1]]`   I gather that these are discrete approximations to continuous equations -- maybe you could write those out.

Comment: @P Lrc. Well, it seems that I misunderstood your question. The above non-iterative algorithm is only usable for the function y(x)=a/(1+exp(bx+c)). As shown in the referenced paper the linearisation thanks to an integral equation is different if the function to be fitted is different. Thus the linear algorithm without initial value is different for each kind of function. So, I understand that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck. Thanks you very much for your comment. I don't have R available here to check what you proposed. But I am confident that would be OK

Comment: @JJacquelin, Since every problem has a different equation could you point out exactly which page or equation this comes specifically for the logistic in your reference.  (Note that you can run R code without having R at this page: https://rdrr.io/snippets   You will need to add `print(a); print(b); print(c)` to see the answer.

Comment: The general case of logistic regression can be found in pages 37-46 of the paper. The above simplified version is not detailed in the paper. The  integral equation used here is : (1/a)*x+(B/y(x))+C=Integal(dx/y(x))=S(x) which approximate is computed by numerical integration.